# Extra divs inside columns (default.xml)

Tags: magento2, sidebar

I need a bit of guidance with Magento 2.

When I use a sidebar (left) page template, the source code looks like this

```
<div class="columns">       
    <div class="column main">...</div>          
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">...</div>         
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-additional">...</div>                   
</div>
```

I'd like to add 3 other divs:

```
<div class="theme-page-content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="columns">               
            <div class="column main">...</div>          
            <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">...</div>         
            <div class="sidebar sidebar-additional">...</div>
        </div>      

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the code I use but it's only for a 1 column page template

```
<container name="main-content-div" label="Main Content Div" as="main-content-div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="theme-page-content">
    <container name="main-content-container" label="Main Content Container" as="main-content-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
    <container name="main-content-row" label="Main Content Row" as="main-content-row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">

        <container name="main-content-column" label="Main Content Column" as="main-content-column" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-12">

            <container name="content" label="Main Content Area"/>

        </container>

    </container>
    </container>
</container>
```

Because of that... it shows on a sidebar page template as:

```
<div class="columns">       
    <div class="column main">

        <div class="theme-page-content">
                <div class="container"> 
                    <div class="row"> ... </div>
                </div>  
            </div>

    </div>          
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">...</div>         
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-additional">...</div>                   
</div>
```

Any help with this is much appreciated. :)

Comment: I'd like to hear this answer as well!